# Map from XKB key names to LDML ISO key names?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, xkb

XKB names keyboard keys with names such as "TLDE" and "AB01"  https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#Fig:KeyNames seen in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` , whereas Unicode's LDML gives keys names such as "B03", "E12" or "C00" https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-keyboards.html#Definitions .

How can I map between these names? Is there a program or table anywhere?

Comment: You can use the "xev" and "showkey" commands to show the scancodes and keycodes will that help.

Answer (score 1):

The two links each give an example which should have made the relationship apparent.

Xkb was introduced in X11R6 (early 1995) with `xkbcomp`, using a grid for the keyboard.  The first page's figure 2 illustrates this (though it dates from later documentation).

There were two `keycodes` files provided in X11R6 (`ibmpc` and `sgi`) and two *symbols* files (`iso9995-3` and `us`), but no documentation for the naming convention, so the reader can only guess that the "A" refers to *alphabetic* keys.  Most of the symbols are 4-characters, a few (such as <kbd>`TAB`</kbd>) have 3.  The second character of the alphabetic grid counts up from the spacebar (A).

Unicode Technical Standard #35 simply copies the *alphabetic* part of the grid, omitting the leading **A**.  (Unicode doesn't really apply to the other keys, of course).